# How to traverse a component tree in React?

Tags: reactjs

Why is this not printing all keys, but only the first key "Component"?

Here is a playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-austin-1hhusc?file=/src/App.tsx

```js
import React from "react";

function printDom(node: React.ReactNode) {
  if (!React.isValidElement(node)) {
    console.log("Not a valid elemenent", node);
    return;
  }

  console.log(node.key);

  React.Children.forEach(node.props.children, (child) => printDom(child));
}

function Container(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  printDom(props.children);
  return <>{props.children}</>;
}

function SuperNestedCompnent() {
  return <div key="div">Hi</div>;
}

function NestedCompnent() {
  return <SuperNestedCompnent key="SuperNestedCompnent" />;
}

function Component() {
  return <NestedCompnent key="NestedComponent" />;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Component key="Component" />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

The console output is only

`Component`

but one would expect

`Component`
`NestedComponent`
`SuperNestedCompnent`
`div`

How would one traverse the tree and print all keys?

Comment: Why would one expect that? Only `Container` has `props.children`, so when you call `printDom`, it prints the `Component` node (which is `Container.props.children`, confusingly named because it's just one child), then does nothing recursively since `Component` has no `props.children`, so there are zero `forEach` iterations to be had and `printDom` returns.

Comment: Wrong. It's called `children` not `descendants`. Children and grandchildren are not the same. It means direct descendants only, no reason to think it's recursively go all the way down the component tree

Comment: Let me rephrase this: how would I traverse this tree and print all keys?

Answer (score 0):

I would share my solution for that

See how I have updated the Components by putting these into

```
function NestedCompnent() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <SuperNestedCompnent key="SuperNestedCompnent" />
    </Container>
  );
}

function Component() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <NestedCompnent key="NestedComponent" />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Also
**Updated the example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-gould-3ufvnt?file=/src/App.tsx**

Comment: Thx, but this does not solve my problem. I don't want to adjust my tree nor put/use something in my components.